# Ubuntu not working on VMware player

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on windows 7 machine using the VMware player. I am not able to login to ubuntu. After I enter my password it comes back to the lock screen. The password i entered is correct. If it is not correct it says invalid password. Only when i enter the correct password it loads the lock screen again in 2-3 secs.

Anyone can help me how to get out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install any toolkit or something? Usually it happens when an external display driver is installed on top of the VM graphics driver. May be the driver is not compatible with in and that is why the display was not working.

If you have installed any toolkit, check if it has any graphics driver within it. If so, Uninstall the toolkit if you have installed any and see if its working.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Even I realized recently. I installed a toolkit that has a graphics driver within in. Its solved now after I uninstalled. Thank You.